# What's to stop me from circumventing CSP nonce by inspecting the response header?

Tags: web, content-security-policy

I'm a little confused on how nonces work with respect to CSP.

For any website I can easily inspect the response header to find the Content-Security-Policy header and from there I could see the nonce that is being allowed.

If I'm able to find the nonce and if I'm able to insert an inline script. I could just add the nonce to my inline script and inject malicious code. How is the nonce secure?

In addition could you use a meta tag to deliver CSP with a nonce?

Answer (score 1):

The web server must provide a unique and unguessable nonce each time. So each time the server sends a response it will set the noonce value at two places

1. on the script tag *(as part of your inline script)* e.g.

   ```
     <script nonce="2726c7f26c">
         var inline = 1;
     </script>
   ```
2. on the csp response header like below:

   ```
      Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-2726c7f26c'
   ```

It is http client responsibility, in this case browser, to ensure these values match before it parses and eval that inline script.

A direct excerpt from MDN:

> A whitelist for specific inline scripts using a cryptographic nonce
>   (number used once). The server must generate a unique nonce value each
>   time it transmits a policy. It is critical to provide an unguessable
>   nonce, as bypassing a resource’s policy is otherwise trivial.

refs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script

Comment: That's true but I can still look at the response header to view the nonce right?

Comment: @SiddGorti you can look it once, but next time server MUST send a different noonce value than the previous one.

Comment: You can look at it, but it's useless knowledge because when you reload the page it will be a different nonce. You can't use the information you gain by looking.  Also: CSP is there to protect end users from websites that may have had malicious content inserted by an outsider. It can in some ways be circumvented by the end user; but why would you?  It's like saying the lock on my front door is problematic because I might leave it unlocked....

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is stopping you, and in fact you can use it to load an external script that wasn't whitelisted, as explained in the article below. To prevent this, you could return [2 CSP headers](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/faq.html#strict-dynamic-with-whitelists), one for the nonce and one for the whitelist. The page will have to satisfy both headers.

> The "strong" policy without strict-dynamic, essentially becomes
> strict-dynamic anyway, since any running script can access the nonce
> from the DOM and use it to load any other script from any origin.

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/w3c/webappsec-csp/458/764973379